# Shifting columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
Date    normPwr_0   normPwr_1   tempNorm_1  tempNorm_2  tempNorm_3  tempNorm_0
6/15/2019    0.89    0.94       0.83        0.88        0.92        0.82 
6/16/2019    0.97    0.89       0.82        0.83        0.88        0.97 
6/17/2019    0.97    0.97       0.97        0.82        0.83        2,188.18
```

I want to shift the column values for only `tempNorm` columns. My desired output is:

```
Date    normPwr_0   normPwr_1   tempNorm_2  tempNorm_3  tempNorm_1
6/15/2019    0.89    0.94       0.83        0.88        0.82 
6/16/2019    0.97    0.89       0.82        0.83        0.97 
6/17/2019    0.97    0.97       0.97        0.82        2,188.18
```

The tricky part is the columns names for `tempNorm`varies such that sometimes I have `[tempNorm_1   tempNorm_2  tempNorm_3  tempNorm_0]` and other times I have
`[tempNorm_4    tempNorm_5  tempNorm_6 tempNorm_7   tempNorm_0]`

When columns have `[tempNorm_4  tempNorm_5  tempNorm_6  tempNorm_7 tempNorm_0]` my desired columns in output dataframe will be `[tempNorm_4 tempNorm_5  tempNorm_6 tempNorm_7]`

Basically I am trying to shift the dataframe in columns name containing `tempNorm` where all values from `tempNorm_0` gets pushed into next higher named column and the highest named column gets dropped off.

I am not sure how to approach this in a clean pythonic way.

**EDIT:**

For `[tempNorm_4 tempNorm_5 tempNorm_6  tempNorm_7 tempNorm_0]`, the values from `tempNorm_0` is moved in to `tempNorm_4` ;the values from `tempNorm_4` is moved in to `tempNorm_5` and so forth. `tempNorm_7` data gets dropped off and is replaced by data from `tempNorm_6`

Comment: when you retain the order for `tempNorm_4 tempNorm_5  tempNorm_6 tempNorm_7` why not for the expected output? am i missing something?

Comment: Please see edit to the question. Hope it clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to `roll` the columns with name `tempNorm_` and drop the last:

```
# get all the tempNorm columns
tmp_cols = np.array([col for col in df.columns if 'tempNorm' in col])

# roll and rename:
df.rename(columns={col:new_col for col, new_col in zip(tmp_cols,np.roll(tmp_cols,-1) ) },
          inplace=True)

# drop the last tempNorm
df.drop(tmp_cols[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
        Date  normPwr_0  normPwr_1  tempNorm_2  tempNorm_3 tempNorm_1
0  6/15/2019       0.89       0.94        0.83        0.88       0.82
1  6/16/2019       0.97       0.89        0.82        0.83       0.97
2  6/17/2019       0.97       0.97        0.97        0.82   2,188.18
```

Comment: Yes I was missing the key word "roll". Thanks for the clever answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### `sorted`, `filter`, `rename`

```
a, b, *c = sorted(df.filter(like='tempNorm'), key=lambda c: int(c.rsplit('_', 1)[1]))
df.drop(b, 1).rename(columns={a: b})

        Date  normPwr_0  normPwr_1  tempNorm_2  tempNorm_3 tempNorm_1
0  6/15/2019       0.89       0.94        0.88        0.92       0.82
1  6/16/2019       0.97       0.89        0.83        0.88       0.97
2  6/17/2019       0.97       0.97        0.82        0.83   2,188.18
```

Comment: Amazing .. took me few minutes to realize what you just compressed in 2 lines of code

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like:

```
m=df.filter(like='tempNorm').sort_index(axis=1)
n=m[m.columns[::-1]].T.shift(-1,axis=0).T.dropna(how='all',axis=1)
pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference(m.columns)],n],axis=1)
```

---

```
        Date  normPwr_0  normPwr_1 tempNorm_3 tempNorm_2 tempNorm_1
0  6/15/2019       0.89       0.94       0.88       0.83       0.82
1  6/16/2019       0.97       0.89       0.83       0.82       0.97
2  6/17/2019       0.97       0.97       0.82       0.97   2,188.18
```